# Postgres Dump and Restore on Linux Terminal

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I need to take a dump in postgres db and to be restored on some other server. please tell me the command in Linux with compressed and encrypted format.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: You should look for solutions before asking a question.

Comment: @Mazzoni, I have tried commands to backup and restoration. But while taking backup its not showing any errors but there is no DDLor DML command inside that file. on some TCL like grant or revoke inside that file. when i try to restore also its not showing any errors because nothing is there in backup file. I have used the following commands

Comment: /Desktop$ pg_dump -hlocalhost -U aa -p5432  oltp_db | gzip > oltp_db.gz
Password:       To restore : /Desktop$ gunzip -c oltp_db.gz | psql -Uaa restore_check
Password:  .                                                                              Can you tell me what i have missed here. why its not taking properly.

Comment: The file that gets generated by pg_dump is text, are you saying that it's actually **empty**? Also, read the [pg_dump manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) there should be spaces in the command line options - `-h localhost` instead of `-hlocalhost`

Comment: @fvu dunno if it's documented anywhere, but `-hlocalhost` is actually fine. @Jeevitha you should have included the details which you are now providing in your question. Your commands look reasonable if a bit klunky to me. Do you see any errors when you run them? How large is the file oltb_db.gz?

Comment: @Josh, I am not seeing any errors while taking dump and restoration.

Comment: @Josh,  File size is very less, its juz 90MB.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pg_dump -Fc`. That'll create a pre-compressed dump suitable for restoration with `pg_restore`. Remember to check the exit code of `pg_dump`.

If you want to encrypt it you'll need to that as a second pass afterwards using the encryption tool of your choice.

Comment: I have tried backup with custom format also. still i am getting an error like pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive while restoration.~Desktop$  pg_dump -hlocalhost -U aa -p5432 -Fc oltp_db | gzip > oltp_db.gz
~Desktop$pg_restore -hlocalhost -U aa -O -C -d restore_check ofbiz_tables_built_trial.gz. can you please provide a solution.

Comment: Don't `gzip` it if you use `-Fc`. It's compressed internally. You would have to unzip it to `pg_restore` it if you `gzip`'d it.

Comment: Its worth it. But one change the database which you are going to take dump should be created under template 0. so then its taking dump properly and letting me to restore. plz correct me if i am wrong.  ~Desktop$ pg_dump -hlocalhost -U aa -p5432 -Fc oltp_db > oltp_db.sql
$Desktop$ pg_restore -hlocalhost -U aa -v  -d restore_check oltp_db.sql

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump -U db_user -p5432 database_name > dump.pgsql`

and then you can gzip it and copy it to the other server , then unzip it there and use  `psql -U db_user -p5432 database_name < dump.pgsql`
to restore the database